# Sides of the polygon marked after deleting the OpenLayers layer

Tags: openlayers, layers, linestring, delete

In other Q&As on the site, @QuentinN helped me to delete the added lines when the user clicks on the map.

They are partially erased and the rest stays there and I don't know why ...
The name of the layer is "line" and also on "line" it tries to delete it.

Can you help me to do this?

```
var array_coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
map.getLayers().forEach(layer => {
    if (layer && layer.get('name') == 'line') {
        console.log(layer);
        map.removeLayer(layer);
    }
});
for (var o = 0; o < array_coordinates[0].length - 1; o++) {
    var point = array_coordinates[0][o];


    PointA = array_coordinates[0][o];
    PointB = array_coordinates[0][o + 1];

    var coordinates = [PointA, PointB];
    var line = new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates);
    dist = line.getLength();


    var line_stile = new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'black'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 10
        }),
        text: new ol.style.Text({
            font: 'bold 19px "Open Sans", "Arial Unicode MS", "sans-serif"',
            placement: 'line',
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'white',
                width: 42
            })
        })
    });

    var layerLines = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates)
            })]
        }),
        name: 'line',
    });

    dist = dist.toFixed(2);
    var data = dist + " m";


    line_stile.getText().setText(data);
    layerLines.setStyle(line_stile);

    map.addLayer(layerLines);



}
```

[image]

When clicking on the polygon I use the method:

```
map.on('click', function(event) {
    console.log("CLICK POP-UP HARTA");
    var extent = ol.extent.createEmpty();
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        console.log(feature);

        var array_coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();

        [....]
    })
})
```

And this means that when you click on the map the basic design and polygons are already loaded by a function when the map is loaded.

Plus, after selecting the polygon on the map, I pick up a pop-up with information about the polygon in the database ...

My information in the database comes from GeoServer. I am very new to this.

This is my function prepare layer:

```
function search_teren(vectorSource, map, color) {
    //console.log("MERGE FUNCTIA");

    proj4.defs('EPSG:31700', '+proj=sterea +lat_0=46 +lon_0=25 +k=0.99975 +x_0=500000 +y_0=500000 +ellps=krass +towgs84=28,-121,-77,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs');
    ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);


    var id_primarie = < ? php echo $_SESSION['user']['data']['id_primarie']; ? > ;
    var mod = "";

    if (id_primarie == 0) {
        mod = 0;
    } else {
        mod = 1;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "server_harta_teren.php?get_data=1&mod=" + mod + "&id_primarie=" + id_primarie,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {

            var polygonsSource = new ol.source.Vector({
                features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(response, {
                    dataProjection: 'EPSG:31700',
                    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
                }),
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
            });
            var vectors = new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: polygonsSource,
                style: styleFunction
            });
            map.addLayer(vectors);

            var selectedFeature = null;



            var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(response);
            var extent = ol.extent.createEmpty();
            var found_extent = 0;

            //console.log(response);  
            //console.log(color.color_imobile);   

            features.forEach(function(feature) {
                feature.setId(undefined);
                feature.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:31700', 'EPSG:3857');
                //ol.extent.extend(extent, feature.getGeometry().getExtent());



                var teren_stile = new ol.style.Style({
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: color.color_imobile
                    }),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: [0, 0, 230],
                        width: 1
                    }),
                    text: new ol.style.Text({
                        font: 'bold 11px "Open Sans", "Arial Unicode MS", "sans-serif"',
                        placement: 'center',
                        //overflow: true,
                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                            color: color.color_eticheta
                        })
                    })
                });

                var selected_stile = new ol.style.Style({
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: color.color_selected
                    }),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: color.color_selected,
                        width: 3
                    }),
                    text: new ol.style.Text({
                        font: 'bold 11px "Open Sans", "Arial Unicode MS", "sans-serif"',
                        placement: 'center',
                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                            color: color.color_eticheta,
                            width: 23
                        })
                    })
                });

                //same id_pdf
                var id_pdf = "";


                var data = "";

                if ($('#etc_tarla').is(":checked")) {
                    data = "T:" + feature.get('tarla') + "  ";
                }
                if ($('#etc_parcela').is(":checked")) {
                    data = data + "P:" + feature.get('parcela') + "  ";
                }
                if ($('#etc_suprafata').is(":checked")) {
                    data = data + "S:" + feature.get('suprafata') + "  MP.";
                }
                if ($('#etc_proprietari').is(":checked")) {
                    data = data + "P:" + feature.get('proprietari') + "  ";
                }
                if ($('#etc_eterra').is(":checked")) {
                    data = data + "C.F.:" + feature.get('e_terra') + "  ";
                }

                //var data = data+"P:"+feature.get('parcela')+"/S:"+feature.get('suprafata')+" MP.Proprietari: "+feature.get('proprietari')+"/E_TERRA:"+feature.get('e_terra');
                //var teren = feature.get('id_teren');
                //console.log(data);


                if (feature.get('layer') == "TEREN") {
                    teren_stile.getText().setText(data);
                    feature.setStyle(teren_stile);
                }



                //console.log(feature.get('text'));

                if (feature.get('text') == id_pdf) {
                    //console.log("merge");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "server_harta_ser.php?get_parcel_info=1&id_pdf=" + id_pdf,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(response) {
                            //console.log(response);

                            //var data = "T:"+response.tarla+"/P:"+response.parcela+"/S:"+response.suprafata+" MP.";

                            selected_stile.getText().setText(data);
                            feature.setStyle(selected_stile);

                        }
                    });

                    ol.extent.extend(extent, feature.getGeometry().getExtent());
                    found_extent = 1;

                }

            });

            if (found_extent == 0) {
                features.forEach(function(feature) {
                    //feature.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:31700', 'EPSG:3857');
                    ol.extent.extend(extent, feature.getGeometry().getExtent());
                });
            }

            vectorSource.teren.clear();
            vectorSource.teren.addFeatures(features);
            //console.log("features:");
            //console.log(features);
            //map.getView().fit(extent);



        }
    });
```

And this is my click event function:

```
//click pe harta pop_up
map.on('clicky', function(event) {
    console.log("CLICK POP-UP HARTA");
    var extent = ol.extent.createEmpty();

    var found = false;
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function(features, layer) {
        var isSelected = !features.get('isSelected');
        features.set('isSelected', isSelected);
        if (selectedFeature && (selectedFeature != features)) {
            selectedFeature.set('isSelected', false);
        }
        selectedFeature = (isSelected) ? features : null;
        found = true;
    })
    if (!found && selectedFeature) {
        selectedFeature.set('isSelected', false);
        selectedFeature = null;
    }



    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        console.log(feature);
        var id_selected_current = feature.get('text');
        console.log("---------------->" + id_selected_current);




        /*
          for(var o = 0; o < array_coordinates[0].length - 1; o++){
                                                              var point  = array_coordinates[0][o];
                                                              
                                                              
                                                              PointA = array_coordinates[0][o];
                                                              PointB = array_coordinates[0][o + 1];
                                                              
                                                              var coordinates = [PointA, PointB];
                                                              var line = new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates);
                                                              dist = line.getLength();
                                                              
                                                              
                                                              var line_stile = new ol.style.Style({
                                                                     fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'black'}),
                                                                     stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                                                       color: 'blue', width: 10
                                                                     }),
                                                                   text: new ol.style.Text({
                                                                     font: 'bold 19px "Open Sans", "Arial Unicode MS", "sans-serif"',
                                                                     placement: 'line',
                                                                     fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                                                       color: 'white', width: 42
                                                                     })
                                                                   })
                                                                 });
                                                              
                                                                 var layerLines = new ol.layer.Vector({
                                                                     source: new ol.source.Vector({
                                                                         features: [new ol.Feature({ geometry: new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates)})]
                                                                     }),
                                                                     name : 'line',
                                                                 });
                                                             
                                                                 dist = dist.toFixed(2);
                                                                 var data = dist + " m";
                                                             
                                                             
                                                                 line_stile.getText().setText(data);
                                                                 layerLines.setStyle(line_stile);
                                                             
                                                                 map.addLayer(layerLines);
                                                               
                                                              
                                                              
                                                        }
         */




        var selected_stile = new ol.style.Style({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: makePattern_click_select_map()
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: [102, 255, 51],
                width: 1
            }),
            text: new ol.style.Text({
                font: 'bold 11px "Open Sans", "Arial Unicode MS", "sans-serif"',
                placement: 'center',
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'white',
                    width: 23
                })
            })
        });




        var data = "";
        if ($('#etc_tarla').is(":checked")) {
            data = "T:" + feature.get('tarla') + "  ";
        }
        if ($('#etc_parcela').is(":checked")) {
            data = data + "P:" + feature.get('parcela') + "  ";
        }
        if ($('#etc_suprafata').is(":checked")) {
            data = data + "S:" + feature.get('suprafata') + "MP.  ";
        }
        if ($('#etc_proprietari').is(":checked")) {
            data = data + "P:" + feature.get('proprietari') + "  ";
        }
        if ($('#etc_eterra').is(":checked")) {
            data = data + "C.F.:" + feature.get('e_terra') + "  ";
        }

        selected_stile.getText().setText(data);
        feature.setStyle(selected_stile);
        ol.extent.extend(extent, feature.getGeometry().getExtent());



        if (feature.get('layer') == "TEREN") {

            var proprietar_tmp = feature.get('proprietari').split('--');
            var crt_proprietar = '<table class="table">';
            if (proprietar_tmp.length > 0) {
                var addit = '';
                for (i = 0; i < proprietar_tmp.length; i++) {
                    if (proprietar_tmp[i].length > 2) {
                        var no = i + 1;
                        crt_proprietar += "<tr><td>" + no + "</td><td><b>" + proprietar_tmp[i] + "</b></td></tr>";
                    }
                }
            }
            crt_proprietar += "</table>";




            //console.log(txt_dist); 


            featureStr = "<h4>Detalii Imobil: </h4>" +
                "<hr />" +
                "<b>" + "Tarla: " + feature.get('tarla') + "</b>" +
                "<br/>" + "<b>" + "Parcela: " + feature.get('parcela') + "</b>" +
                "<br/>" + "<b>" + "Suprafa&#355&#259;: " + ((feature.get('suprafata') != "") ? (feature.get('suprafata') + " MP") : '') + "</b>" +
                "<br/>" + "<b>" + "Identificator CF: " + feature.get('e_terra') + "</b>" +
                "<br/><br />" + "<b>" + "Proprietari: " + crt_proprietar + "</b>"

                +
                "<table class='table' style='font-size: 60%'>" +
                "" + "<tr><td><a href='edit_pdf.php?id=" + feature.get('text') + "' target='blank_" + feature.get('tarla') + "' ref='noopener noreferrer'>" + "<button class='btn btn-success' style='color: white;'>Adaug&#259; Informa&#355;ii" + "</a></td>" +
                "" + "<td><button class='btn btn-success' onclick='descarca_single_teren(" + feature.get('text') + ")'>Descarc&#259; KML</td></tr>" +
                "</table>";
        } else if (feature.get('layer') == "CONSTRUCTIE") {
            featureStr = "<h4>Detalii Construc&#355;ie: </h4>" +
                "<hr />" +
                "<b>" + "Numar Construc&#355;ie: " + feature.get('numar_const') + "</b>" +
                "<br /><b>Folosin&#355;&#259; Construc&#355;ie: " + feature.get('folosinta') + "</b>" +
                "<br /><b>Suprafa&#355;&#259;: " + feature.get('suprafata') + " MP.</b>" +
                "<br />" +
                "<table class='table' style='font-size: 60%'>" +
                "<tr><td><a href='edit_pdf.php?id=" + feature.get('id') + "' target='blank_'>" + "<button class='btn btn-success' style='color: white;'>Adauga Informa&#355;ii" + "</a></td>" +
                "</table>";
        } else {
            featureStr = "<h4>IN LUCRU... </h4>";
        }




        content.innerHTML = featureStr;
        overlay.setPosition(getCenterOfExtent(extent));

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "ser_edit_pdf.php",
            data: {
                get_setari_harta_mica: 1
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {

                var color = data;

                if ($('#mod_cautare1').is(":checked")) {


                    imobile.getSource().forEachFeature(function(featuree) {
                        //feature.setId(feature.get('text'));
                        //console.log(feature.getProperties());
                        //console.log(feature.layer);


                        var style = new ol.style.Style({
                            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                color: color.color_imobile
                            }),
                            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                color: [0, 0, 230],
                                width: 1
                            }),
                            text: new ol.style.Text({
                                font: '15px Calibri,sans-serif',
                                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                    color: color.color_eticheta
                                }),
                                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                    color: '#fff',
                                    width: 1
                                })
                            })
                        });


                        if (id_selected_current != featuree.get('text')) {
                            label_teren_setup(style, featuree);
                        }



                    });


                    constructii.getSource().forEachFeature(function(featuree) {
                        //feature.setId(feature.get('text'));
                        //console.log(feature.getProperties());
                        //console.log(feature.layer);


                        var style = new ol.style.Style({
                            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                color: color.color_constructii
                            }),
                            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                color: [0, 0, 230],
                                width: 1
                            }),
                            text: new ol.style.Text({
                                font: '15px Calibri,sans-serif',
                                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                    color: color.color_const
                                }),
                                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                    color: '#fff',
                                    width: 1
                                })
                            })
                        });


                        if (id_selected_current != featuree.get('text')) {
                            label_teren_setup(style, featuree);
                        }



                    });


                    search.getSource().forEachFeature(function(featuree) {
                        //feature.setId(feature.get('text'));
                        //console.log(feature.getProperties());
                        //console.log(feature.layer);


                        var style_selected = new ol.style.Style({
                            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                color: makePattern()
                            }),
                            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                color: [0, 0, 230],
                                width: 1
                            }),
                            text: new ol.style.Text({
                                font: '15px Calibri,sans-serif',
                                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                    color: color.color_eticheta
                                }),
                                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                    color: '#fff',
                                    width: 1
                                })
                            })
                        });


                        if (id_selected_current != featuree.get('text')) {
                            label_teren_setup(style_selected, featuree);

                        }



                    });


                }


                if ($('#mod_cautare2').is(":checked") || $('#imobile_non_cadgen').is(":checked")) {


                    imobile_non_cadgen.getSource().forEachFeature(function(featuree) {
                        //feature.setId(feature.get('text'));
                        //console.log(feature.getProperties());
                        //console.log(feature.layer);


                        var style = new ol.style.Style({
                            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                color: color.color_imobile_ancpi
                            }),
                            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                color: [0, 0, 230],
                                width: 1
                            }),
                            text: new ol.style.Text({
                                font: '15px Calibri,sans-serif',
                                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                    color: color.color_eticheta
                                }),
                                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                    color: '#fff',
                                    width: 1
                                })
                            })
                        });


                        if (id_selected_current != featuree.get('text')) {
                            label_teren_setup(style, featuree);
                        }



                    });


                    constructii_non_cadgen.getSource().forEachFeature(function(featuree) {
                        //feature.setId(feature.get('text'));
                        //console.log(feature.getProperties());
                        //console.log(feature.layer);


                        var style = new ol.style.Style({
                            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                color: color.color_constructii_ancpi
                            }),
                            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                color: [0, 0, 230],
                                width: 1
                            }),
                            text: new ol.style.Text({
                                font: '15px Calibri,sans-serif',
                                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                    color: color.color_const
                                }),
                                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                    color: '#fff',
                                    width: 1
                                })
                            })
                        });


                        if (id_selected_current != featuree.get('text')) {
                            label_teren_setup(style, featuree);
                        }



                    });




                    search_non_cadgen.getSource().forEachFeature(function(featuree) {
                        //feature.setId(feature.get('text'));
                        //console.log(feature.getProperties());
                        //console.log(feature.layer);


                        var style_selected = new ol.style.Style({
                            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                color: makePattern()
                            }),
                            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                color: [0, 0, 230],
                                width: 1
                            }),
                            text: new ol.style.Text({
                                font: '15px Calibri,sans-serif',
                                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                    color: color.color_eticheta
                                }),
                                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                    color: '#fff',
                                    width: 1
                                })
                            })
                        });


                        if (id_selected_current != featuree.get('text')) {
                            label_teren_setup(style_selected, featuree);

                        }



                    });




                }

            }

        })


    });

    map.getView().fit(extent, {
        size: map.getSize()
    });

});
```

Comment: For integration see JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/wtmv6r83/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without trying to find out where the problem with deleting layers is, I propose a different strategy of styling your selected polygon, by combination of custom style function and custom feature property. Logic is as follows:

- Custom feature property `isSelected` (set by `feature.set('isSelected, true)`) is used to turn selected style on or off.
- Custom style function returns either default style or selected style, depending on value of `isSelected` property.
- In custom style function selected style is created using measured lines as geometries. Selected style is created only once and saved for later use in custom feature property `selectedStyle`.

Code could then look something like this (works for polygon features, for other types it should be modified):

```
var defaultStyle = new ol.layer.Vector().getStyleFunction()();

function styleFunction(feature, resolution) {
  if (!feature.get('isSelected')) return(defaultStyle);
  
  var selectedStyle = feature.get('selectedStyle');
  if (selectedStyle) return(selectedStyle);
  
  var point, PointA, PointB, coordinates, line, dist, data, line_stile;
  var style = [defaultStyle[0]];
  var array_coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
  for (var o = 0; o < array_coordinates[0].length - 1; o++) {
    point = array_coordinates[0][o];     
    PointA = array_coordinates[0][o];
    PointB = array_coordinates[0][o + 1];
    coordinates = [PointA, PointB];
    line = new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates);
    dist = line.getLength();
    line_stile = new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'black'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'blue',
        width: 10
      }),
      text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: 'bold 19px "Open Sans", "Arial Unicode MS", "sans-serif"',
        placement: 'line',
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'white',
          width: 42
        })
      }),
      geometry: line
    });
    dist = dist.toFixed(2);
    data = dist + " m";
    line_stile.getText().setText(data);
    style.push(line_stile);
  }
  feature.set('selectedStyle', style);
  return(style);
}

var polygonsSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: sourceDataUrl,
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
});
var vectors = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: polygonsSource,
  style: styleFunction
});
map.addLayer(vectors);
```

Now all you have to do to show desired feature/polygon as selected is to set:

```
feature.set('isSelected', true);
```

and to return it to default style:

```
feature.set('isSelected', false);
```

Here is working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/wtmv6r83/. Clicking on polygon selects it, clicking on selected polygon unselects it, clicking outside polygons unselects currently selected polygon.

Comment: I implemented the code from @TomazicM but it doesn't work for me when I click on the polygon it marks it pops up but it doesn't mark the sides and it doesn't write their size :( I'm very early and I honestly have no idea what else I could do with him, can you please implement your solution in my code?

Thank you very much, I'm very early and I just don't realize what I'm doing wrong here .....

I edited the question with the two functions I use. Thank you from the bottom of my heart

Comment: JSFiddle example is the most I can do for you. If you understand it, you'll have no problems implementing it. If you don't understand it, take your time to understand it.